# Special characters converting to underscore in excel sheet name using excel oledb

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my query for Excel OldeDB:

```
"CREATE TABLE [test++]  ([StandardEquipment] string)"
```

But its creating the sheet name with underscore "test__". So how can I create excel sheet with plus char.